# Sublime Text 3 : HaoIDE all options disabled

Tags: force.com, force.com-ide, sublime, haoide

I have been using Sublime Text 3 : HaoIDE for Force.com Development for last 4 months. After I updated Sublime Text 3 to build 3114, all options under HaoIDE menu are disabled, restricting me from creating any new projects or working on existing projects.

Has anyone come across a similar issue? Please share a method to solve this.

For addition information on HaoIDE [click here](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide).

Comment: https://github.com/xjsender/haoide/issues/112 ?

Comment: @kurunve hey thanks! Let me try it out and get back to you..

Comment: @kurunve thanks! it worked!! I downgraded to build 3103 and now it works fine.

Comment: @DnyaneshKC, as you can see at the end part of the [issue #112](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide/issues/112 ), @pfronczak also give us a option to enable ``haoide`` in ``sublime 3114``, I already tried to do it as @pfronczak said, it's working perfectly.